# In PyCharm, when searching a list by typing, how to jump between search results?

Tags: pycharm, quick-search

In PyCharm, in any window featuring a list, I can start typing a substring, and this instantly brings me to the first list element that has that substring:

[image: search result]

Now, **how can I jump to the next search result (i.e. the next element matching the substring)?**

Tried <kbd>F3</kbd> (no effect) and <kbd>Enter</kbd> (the "Search for:" widget just disappears).
Also tried googling "pycharm quick search start typing" and such but this only locates help on "search everywhere" which is not this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately asked JetBrains support, and they said:

> Please try using <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> buttons on your keyboard. Does it work?

And indeed, it worked!

Who could've thought...